# Distribution derived from beta distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ ~ $\beta$$(a,1)$ and $Y$ ~ $\beta$$(b,1)$.

What will be the distribution of $\frac {X} {X+Y}$ ?

Comment: Please add your attempts to solve the problem in order to avoid massive downvotes (on my answer, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and with densities (supported on $(0,1)$) given by $f_X(x)=\frac{x^{a-1}}{a}$ and $f_Y(x)=\frac{x^{b-1}}{b}$, then $Z=\frac{X}{X+Y}\in[0,1]$ and for any $t\in[0,1]$ we have:

$$\mathbb{P}\left[Z\leq t\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{Y}\leq\frac{t}{1-t}\right]=1-\mathbb{P}\left[Y\leq \frac{1-t}{t}\,X\right].\tag{1}$$
If $t\geq\frac{1}{2}$,
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[Y\leq \frac{1-t}{t}\,X\right] = \frac{1}{ab}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{1-t}{t}x}x^{a-1}y^{b-1}\,dy\,dx=\frac{\left(-1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^b}{ab^2(a+b)}.\tag{2}$$
If $0\leq t\leq\frac{1}{2}$,
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[Y\leq \frac{1-t}{t}\,X\right] = 1-\frac{1}{ab}\int_{0}^{\frac{t}{1-t}}\int_{\frac{1-t}{t}x}^{1}x^{a-1}y^{b-1}\,dy\,dx=1-\frac{\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^a}{a^2 b(a+b)}.\tag{3} $$
By differentiating with respect to $t$, we have that the PDF of $Z$ is given by:

> $$ f_Z(t) = \frac{ab}{a+b}\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{t^{a-1}}{(1-t)^{a+1}}&\text{if}& 0\leq t \leq\frac{1}{2},\\\frac{(1-t)^{b-1}}{t^{b+1}}&\text{if}&\frac{1}{2}\leq t\leq 1, \end{array}\right.\tag{4}$$

hence we may say that $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is "piecewise beta-distributed".